# How to get duration of videos from URLs in spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have a very loooong list of YouTube videos (in Google sheets) and want to get their duration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can pull it using importxml:

```
=IMPORTXML("youtube url","//*[@itemprop='duration']/@content")
```

the format comes back as PT7M54S which means 7 min 54 seconds so if you want to transform it you can do this:

```
=REGEXREPLACE(IMPORTXML("youtube url","//*[@itemprop='duration']/@content"),"(PT)(\d+)M(\d+)S","$2:$3")
```

[image]